# booleans in for loop

Tags: java, loops, boolean

why does this work

```
 for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("printing " + i);
    }
```

but not this? it's accepted by the compiler, but it won't print anything when run

```
for(int j = 10; j == 1; j--) {
    System.out.println("printing " + j);
}
```

I'm really sorry if it's a stupid question :/
it should be just the same boolean, is it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're running the loop while `j` equals 1; but it starts with 10. What you want would be this:

```
for(int j = 10; j != 1; j--) {
    System.out.println("printing " + j);
}
```

Here, you run the loop while `j` is **not** equal to 1.

**Edit:** The original failing loop could be automatically transformed to the following `while` loop:

```
{
    int j = 10;
    while(j == 1) {
        System.out.println("printing " + j);
        j--;
    }
}
```

This explains more clearly, why it never ran.

Comment: ah, now I get it, the second expression means running while the expression still true, not an expression to indicate where the loop will stop. thanks :D

Comment: @Rei Correct. A very important distinction.

Answer (score 2):

First, the *initialization* is done (it's only executed once, on the first iteration):

```
int j = 10
```

then, the *termination* expression is evaluated:

```
j == 1
```

Since `j` is 10, `j == 1` will be `10 == 1`, which is `false`.

The loop *termination* indicates that the loop must finish, so the *body* of the loop is **never** executed.

**Summary**: If the *termination* expression is `true`, the body of the loop will be executed. If it's `false`, the body won't be executed and the loop will finish.

Comment: I don't understand, the if the termination expression is true, then the loop will be terminated correct? if the expression is still false, why the body of loop is never executed?

Comment: If the *termination* expression is `true`, the body of the loop will be executed. If it's `false`, the body won't be executed and the loop will finish.

Comment: @Rei Accept the answer to close this question. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int j = 10; j == 1; j--) {...}
```

At very first iteration `j==1` or `10==1` will be false and loop will break.

`for(int j = 10; j != 0; j--) {...}` This will work.

Answer (score 1):

The `termination expression` `j == 1` is always `false` in the for loop in your case.

That is why it is not going inside the loop and printing anything.

From Java Doc - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

```
When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
```

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax is :

```
for (intialization; condition; iteration/recursion)
{
    // Loop entered if condition evaluates to true.

   // At end of loop, recursion condition updated and loop continues based on condition

}// Loop terminates when condition evaluates to false;
```

In your case,

```
for(int j = 10; j == 1; j--) {
    System.out.println("printing " + j);
}

// You have initialized j=10, but since j!= 1, the loop is not being entered.
```

To make it work, you replace the condition j==1 to j>=1

```
 for(int j = 10; j >= 1; j--) {
    System.out.println("printing " + j);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop condition will never be true as you are starting with j = 10 and condition j == 1 which will always be false. Instead try something like.

```
for(int j = 10; j != 1; j--){
  system.out.println("Printing: " + j)
}
```

OR

```
for(int j = 10; j > 1; j--){
  system.out.println("Printing: " + j)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you question is basic question about for loop

in upper for loop you give a range like my loop is rotate 10 times reversely means 0 to time times print your result
like,

printing 10
printing 9
printing 8
.
.
.
.
printing 1

last loop wont print any thing coz cant satisfied the condition j == 1

hope you understand..

Comment: No Second Loop Won't print anything.

Comment: yes ! you are right second loop won't print anything coz the variable j can't fulfil the condition...

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your second loop for terminating condition. It should be like

```
for(int j = 10; j > 1; j--) {
     System.out.println("printing " + j);
}
```